# maven does not recognize suiteXmlFile parameter

Tags: maven, testng

I use maven surefire plug-in to execute testng-selenium tests
I was wanting to parameterize suiteXmlFile so that I can pass suite xml file from command line. Plugin looks like -

[image]

But maven does not let me use this parameter. Did I miss any thing?
I am using testng 6.8.7

Comment: Have you defined a property called `suiteXmlFile`?

Comment: added property and it works now. Could you mark your comment as answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven expands the expression `${suiteXmlFile}` to the value of a property. It can be defined

1. via a node the `<properties>` node of the `pom.xml` or
2. from the JVM system property passed to `mvn` using `-D<name>=<value>`.

Find further infos on [resource filtering in the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

You should define a property called `suiteXmlFile` pointing to a suite XML file.